# Solr - getting error with full-import by cUrl

Tags: php, curl, solr

I have a big DB in MySql and trying to import all data in new core. 
I wrote script where call data-import command by cUrl

```
$url = 'http://localhost:8080/solr/products/dataimport';
$fields = array(
    'debug' => false,
    'commit' => true,
    'command' => 'full-import',
    'optimize' => false,
    'indent' => true,
    'rows' => $count,
    'start' => $start,
    'verbose' => false,
    'clean' => $cleanSolr, // true at first time and false after it
    'wt' => 'json',
);

$url = 'http://localhost:8080/solr/products/dataimport?' . http_build_query($fields);

error_log($url);
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

But always this request clean all data and import in empty core at both times, when `clean = true` and `clean = false`

can you help me with this issue ?

Comment: Other code is probably changing your variable value before or after this portion

Comment: There is no other code :/